# C# mvc multiline textbox valid json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC application with a multiline textbox in a form on a page;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "job_create-form", role = "form"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Label("Notes", new {@class = "form-label"})
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, new {@class = "form-input", @placeholder = "Please add your notes"})

    <input type="submit" class="button secondary" value="Submit" />
}
```

With the textbox being multiline means the user can hit the return/enter key and generate a new line within the text box - I'm struggling to create valid JSON as a consequence of that.

When I submit to the controller I want to generate an output file.
I have been validating my JSON against this site; https://jsonlint.com/
But I can't seem to quite get there.

Here is my controller and helper method;

```
public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
{
    string path = @"C:\json.txt";

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
    }

    model.Notes = CleanNotes(model.Notes);

    using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("{");
        sw.WriteLine($"    \"JobName\": \"John Smith\",");
        sw.WriteLine($"    \"Notes\": \"{model.Notes}\",");
        sw.WriteLine($"    \"Title\": \"Sir\"");
        sw.WriteLine("}");
    }

    return View();
}

private string CleanNotes(string notes)
{
    if (notes.Contains("\n"))
    {
        notes = notes.Replace("\n", "\\\n");
    }

     return notes;
}
```

I'm not sure how to make this valid JSON.
Any pointers?

Comment: Have you consider just using the [DataContractJsonSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data)

Comment: Or [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) or [tag:json.net]?  All these will serialize your model for you correctly.

Comment: I don't want to send the whole model to the client.  The only reason to write it like this is to avoid creating yet another object that is only slightly different to the other who knows how many that are similar.  But if that's the recommended way then that's what I'll do.  I was keen to figure out how to do this though.

Comment: If you don't want to define another explicit type, just serialize an appropriate [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).

Comment: @dbc Perfect, thank you, that did the trick.  Should I post the code I got to work? (comment or reply?)

Comment: @Boomer - sure, you can always [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dbc's advice I created an anonymous object and serialized it;

```
var obj = new
{
    JobName = "John Smith",
    Notes = model.Notes,
    Title = "Sir"
};

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var output = serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

Then wrote the 'output' variable to file.
Thanks for the help :)